# why has "was" been omitted in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> We could just see the train approaching in the distance.

This sentence has been taken from Cambridge Dictionary. To know the meaning of "approach" I searched in this dictionary and I found this sentence.

If this sentence would be written in the following way, it would seem natural to me.

> We could just see (that) the train was approaching in the distance.

I cannot understand why "was" has been omitted. In which cases this sort of omossion is allowed?

Answer (score 2):

These are two *different* ways of expressing the idea. The second version is not a reduced clause, where **that** is omitted.

> We saw that the train was approaching in the distance.
>
> We saw the train approaching in the distance.

The object of **saw** in the first sentence is expressed as a *that*-clause.

**We saw *that*...**

The object of **saw** in the second sentence is expressed as a noun-phrase (**the train**) modified by a participial phrase (**approaching in the distance**).

**We saw *the train approaching*...**

Compare:

> I heard him knocking on the door.
>
> I heard that he was knocking on the door.

Answer (score 1):

"Approaching" here used as gerund or participle... Verb is already present there---- could see-, and we don't use   was, am, etc  with model verb