# Is there a missing "was?"

Tags: verbs, object-complements

> We thought it our duty to take care of the orphans.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct or is there a missing "was?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why has "was" been omitted in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87428/why-has-was-been-omitted-in-this-sentence)

Comment: @PeterJennings in the link you provided train-approaching is noun-participle.  In this current question "it our-duty" is "noun noun".  Are they really the same type of phrase?

Comment: @Sam OK Sam, you are probably right, but I'm pretty sure that this question has been asked and answered here in some form before.

Comment: “to think it [to be] something” may be formally dubious, but is a well established idiom.  The first example to come to my mind: Monty Python put the phrase “We thought it best that …” in the mouth of a stuffy banker-type in the Architect Sketch.

Comment: To this native speaker of American English, OP’s example sentence sounds better as is than it would with *was* inserted. Maybe I’m stuffy… but I’ve never worked in a bank.

Comment: You might want to look up **ditransitive verbs**.  Certain verbs in English are ditransitive, which means they can take two objects, like "I gave Paul the book" with no preposition or other verb.  *To think* is one of these ditransitive verbs when it means "to have an opinion".

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct and includes an "object complement". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_complement) provides a decent definition:

> In grammar, an object complement is a predicative expression that follows a direct object of an attributive ditransitive verb or resultative verb and that complements the direct object of the sentence by describing it.

In this case, the object complement "our duty" follows the direct object "it" of the attributive ditransitive verb "thought" and complements "it" by describing it. Because "our duty" is a nominal phrase, it is a "nominal" (or "nominative") object complement (as opposed to an "adjectival" one).